# A nontrivial subgroup of $G$ contained in every other nontrivial subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is from a collection of past master's exams.

> Let $G$ be a group with a subgroup $H$ as described in the title. I'd like to show that $H$ is in the center of $G$.

My intuition is to choose some element $x\in H$ (and thus in every nontrivial subgroup $K$ of $G$) and then apply the counting formula; i.e. the order of $G$ is the product of the order of the centralizer of $x$ with that of its conjugacy class. I feel like this, together with the class equation, should tell me everything I need to know. It's been awhile since I've done a problem like this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the center of $G$ is nontrivial, $H$ is contained in the center by the very definition of $H$. Therefore all you have to prove is that if the center of $G$ is trivial, so is $H$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Wait $G$ is finite?

Comment: The intersection of the non trivial subgroups of $G$ is non trivial, so $G$ cannot be residually finite. A fortiori, it cannot be finite.

Comment: @Seirios: no that is not true: residually finite is about intersections of finite-index subgroups, not non-trivial ones.  For example, apply your reasoning to the cylic group of order 4.

Comment: @SteveD: Exact, my reasoning works only for infinite groups.

Comment: Consider $G = Z_8$, $H = \{ 0,4\}$ as an example of abelian group, and $G = Q_8$, $H = \{ 0,-1\}$ as an example of non-abelian group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary element $g\in G$. $g$ induces the cyclic subgroup $C:=\{g^n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$. Since $C$ is nontrivial (unless $g$ is the neutral element), $H$ must, by definition, be a subgroup of $C$. But all elements of $C$ commute with $g$, by construction. Therefore since $H$ is a subgroup of $C$, all elements of $H$ also commute with $g$. But $g$ was chosen arbitrary, thus all elements of $H$ commute with *every* element of $G$, thus $H$ is a subgroup of the center.

Comment: Systematic and to the point. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

For each $x \in G$, $C_G(x)$ is nontrivial, hence $H \subseteq C_G (x)$.
Therefore, $H \subseteq \mathop  \cap \limits_{x \in G} C_G (x) = Z(G)$

Answer (score 2):

The classification of such groups is simple in two cases:

- If *G* is a **finite group**, then *G* has a non-identity subgroup *H* contained in every non-identity subgroup if and only if *G* is either non-identity cyclic of prime power order or a (generalized) quaternion 2-group.
- If *G* is an **abelian group**, then *G* has a non-identity subgroup *H* contained in every non-identity subgroup if and only if *G* is either non-identity cyclic of prime power order or a Prüfer *p*-group, $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$.

The first is well known (for instance, Gorenstein's Finite Groups textbook, Theorem 5.4.10.ii page 199). The second is also easy: *H* is by definition essential and clearly has order *p* for some prime *p*, so *G* is contained in a maximal essential extension of *H*, and all such groups are Prüfer *p*-groups.

I suspect the classification for general groups is also fairly easy: presumably just the infinite generalized quaternion 2-group. However, I neither proved this nor found a classification.

By the above arguments (in other answers), *G* is a *p*-group and *H* is a central subgroup of order *p*, and both the finite and abelian subgroups of *G* are known.