# Do noncyclic groups of order $p^n$, $n>1$ always have a subgroup isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$?

Tags: group-theory

If $p=2$, then the quaternion group is a counterexammple, so let $p$ be an odd prime. Are there any groups like the quaternion groups for odd primes (i.e., they have a center of order $p$ and every nontrivial subgroup contains the center) that would also serve as counterexamples?

Comment: No, if $p$ is an odd prime, any non-cyclic $p$-group has an elementary Abelian subgroup of order $p^{2}.$

Comment: How do you prove that?

Comment: Here are references to Gorenstein and Hall: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801860/unique-minimal-subgroup/801893

Comment: Thanks Jack,saves me doing it again!

Comment: Hmm, that sort of answers the 2nd part of my question, but I still don't see why that implies that every noncyclic odd $p$ group has $C_p\times C_p$ as a subgroup.

Comment: You might also be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185748/a-nontrivial-subgroup-of-g-contained-in-every-other-nontrivial-subgroup/186211#186211

Comment: @Nishant: let me know if something isn't clear. A "minimal subgroup" of a group is a subgroup of prime order. Every element of prime order generates such a subgroup. If you take one element $\langle z \rangle$ of prime order in the center, and one element $x$ of prime order from anywhere other than $\langle z \rangle$ (so from any other minimal subgroup), then $\langle x,z \rangle \cong C_p \times C_p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. The only $p$-groups with no subgroups isomorphic to $C_p \times C_p$ are the cyclic groups of order $p^n$ and the quaternion groups of order $2^{n+3}$ for $n \geq 0$.

This is Theorem 5.4.10.ii on page 199 of Gorenstein's *Finite Groups*, Theorem 12.5.2 on page 189 of M. Hall's *Theory of Groups*, Theorem 5.3.7 on page 114 of Kurzweil–Stellmacher's *Theory of Finite Groups*, Theorem 6.11 on page 189 of Isaacs's *Finite Group Theory*, Satz III.8.2 on page 310 Of Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen*, Proposition 5.3.6 on page 136 of Robinson's textbook for a *Course in the Theory of Groups*, Theorem IV and V in §62-63 on pages 73-75 in Burnside's *Theory of Groups* (1ed), and Theorem V and VI in §104-105 on pages 131-132 of Burnside's *Theory of Groups* (2ed). Aschbacher's *Finite Group Theory* is another standard reference, but it only contains the reduction as proposition 23.9 on page 109 (the actual result though is exercise 4 on page 115).

None of the proofs are particularly short, but all are pretty easy to read.

---

In particular, every non-cyclic, non-quaternion finite $p$-group contains a subgroup $C_p \times C_p$. If we assume $Z(G)$ has order $p$, then $C_p \times C_p$ cannot equal $Z(G)$, so either it intersects it trivially or $Z(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $C_p \times C_p$ and any complement to $Z(G)$ intersects it trivially. Thus we have proved:

**Proposition** If $G$ is a finite $p$-group with $|Z(G)|=p$ which contains no non-identity subgroup intersecting the center trivially, then $G$ is cyclic or quaternion.

Comment: Derek Robinson's is the shortest so far